# ClickHouse correlated subquery

Tags: clickhouse

I've some table. Each date contains data snapshots for 15 days ago and 50 days ahead. If I'll go to my table and run SELECT WHERE date = '2022-01-27' I will get rows with block_date from 2022-01-13 to 2022-03-18. I need to build reports per month, so at date = '2022-01-27' I need to see rows with block_date from 2022-01-01 to 2022-01-31. I can find this missing information if I go back a day.
I tried to run query below to achieve this, but I got an error and according to these docs: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/operators/exists/ I can't use EXISTS here. How can I modify my query? I don't have any ideas.

```
 SELECT
      `date`,
      block_date,
      total_plan_volume_grp20
    FROM schema.table 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      addDays(`date`, 1),
      block_date,
      total_plan_volume_grp20
    FROM schema.table t1
    where exists (
       select true 
       from schema.table t2 
       where t2.`date` = addDays(t1.`date`, 1))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      addDays(`date`, 2),
      block_date,
      total_plan_volume_grp20
    FROM schema.table t1
    where exists (
       select true 
       from schema.table t2 
       where t2.`date` = addDays(t1.`date`, 2)
```

Comment: Can you share the exact text of the error please?

Comment: Missing columns: 't1.date' while processing query: 'SELECT true FROM schema.table AS t2 WHERE date = addDays(t1.date, 1)', required columns: 'date' 't1.date', maybe you meant: ['date']: While processing 1 IN (SELECT 1 FROM (SELECT true FROM schema.table AS t2 WHERE t2.date = addDays(t1.date, 1)) LIMIT 1). (UNKNOWN_IDENTIFIER) (version 22.10.2.11 (official build))